# How do I solve this issue: process finished with exit code -1066598274 (0xC06D007E)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-stl

I am trying to use the numpy-stl library to rotate a triangular mesh, but the process keeps failing. For reference, this is the code I am running:

```
from stl import mesh
import math

sphere = mesh.Mesh.from_file('bones.stl')
sphere.rotate([0.0, 1, 0.0], math.radians(90), [0,0,0])
print(sphere.points[0])
```

But it never gets to print the result. Instead it gives out this message:

```
Process finished with exit code -1066598274 (0xC06D007E)
```

Why is this? I am unable to find any similar issues online, and I have tried loading different files to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by unmatched version of `numpy` and other libraries. Try reinstall all dependencies.